# What is the difference between UML extension and generalization

Tags: uml

I have searched for a lot of posts on internet and still not knowing to differentiate sometimes between extension and generalization or if it is another use case not related to another.

For example, I'm trying to build  a system about a restaurant. And to print the ticket, the waiter can introduce the order number if he remembers it, but if he doesn't remember it he can search in a not paid order list and select the ticket from there.
I believe that in this case it will be an extension of printing ticket(being printing ticket the default one by typing the order) and then an extension of select from order list.
Or it could be a generalization?.

Comment: For this particular case neither extension nor generalization is necessary. What you describe fits an alternative path

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is a lot of cases where while modelling we tend to try using extension or generalization but neither of them is needed. To make this difference it has to make sense add the new element, e.g. there are different actors in more general and more specific use cases or the part extending a use case can either exist as a separate UC, adds new actors or is a re-useable part (the latter might not be enough to separate it though).

Generalization means that the use cases serve the same purpose but they are performed in a (very) different way. Imagine a payment. You can have a generic (parent) UC called Pay to which only one actor - User is associated. But you can also have payments with various external payment method providers, like credit card agent, fast wire transfer agent and so on. Each of those payments introduce additional actor and is performed differently so they might require considering being specialisations of the Pay UC.

In terms of extension, imagine you have two UCs: Create a client and Place an order. Often you can start placing an order and create a client on the fly. On the other hand, you can create an order for an existing client or you can create a client upfront even before the first order. So the two aforementioned UCs can be run on their own, but also Create a client extends Place an order.

In your case, search in a not paid order list will be just an alternative flow of the UC so unless there are other reasons it will most probably be requiring neither an extension nor generalization.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let you drag into functional decomposition with use cases. Use cases shall show the added value for an actor using the system under consideration.

Generalizing as well as `<<extend>>` relations are a good indicator for starting functional decomposition. Don't! The first is (from my perspective) an absolute no-go. Since an added value is unique per se, a use of generalization creates an oxymoron. I think that there is only one case for a generalization and that's called franchise.

The use of `<<extend>>` especially indicates functional decomposition. People start pulling out functional parts from a use case and make it a bubble. But they are no use cases as they deliver no added value on their own. At least in the most cases.

So the simple advise: stay away from both generalization and `<<extend>>` (as well as `<<include>>`) unless you know exactly what you're doing. Just create meaningful actor-use case relations. Full stop.